# compare a string with NSMutablearray data in xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsmutablearray

I have a NSMutableArray and I need to compare the content in it with a NSString..But couldn't get it ?

My array

```
(
{
  Code=Sunday;
},
{
 Code=Monday;
},
{
Code=Tuesday;
}
)
```

I m comparing like this :

```
BOOL isTheObjectThere = [array containsObject:weekday];

if([arr count]==0 && isTheObjectThere==YES)
{
//do something
}
else
{
//do something
}
```

Here weekday is NSString whose value=Sunday

But isTheObjectThere is returning NO..

Where Im going wrong?

Comment: this is  a common issue while using the method [array containsObject:x];, so its better to use the method shown in the answer below, but will consume more time as the contents of the array increases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array contains dictionary elements, then retrieve values of key(Code).

```
 NSMutableArray *yourArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {
        [yourArray addObject:[dict valueForKey:@"Code"]];
    }
    BOOL isTheObjectThere = [yourArray containsObject:@"Sunday"];
```

Comment: @Sindhia: It means you didn't get answer or didn't understand.

Comment: I didn't get answer .it is returning NO when a match occurs...what elz should I need to modify?

Comment: NSLog(@"your array:%@",yourArray); May i know what the output is?

Comment: (
{
  Code=Sunday;
},
{
 Code=Monday;
},
{
Code=Tuesday;
}
)

Comment: This is your getting array. But i have written code using this array. array = ( { Code=Sunday; }, { Code=Monday; }, { Code=Tuesday; } ). From this array, i derived another array(yourArray). The result: yourArray = (Sunday,Monday,Tuesday)

Answer (score 1):

see this example

```
NSMutableArray* array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Sunday", @"Monday", @"Tuesday", nil];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@", array];
BOOL isTheObjectThere = [predicate evaluateWithObject:@"Sunday"];
NSLog(@"isTheObjectThere %d",isTheObjectThere);
```

its work fine and return **isTheObjectThere 1**

Comment: No actually my array is NSMutableArray and I need to check some condition after getting BOOL value...I have edited my code ..Can u please have a look and rectify my mistake ..

Comment: @Sindhia i think you want to add the sunday value in another array right??

Comment: yes dude i know that sunday is string but i say that i think you want to add sunday if isThere Bool value return yes.. ok now 'use this dude.. NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@", theArray];
BOOL result = [predicate evaluateWithObject:theString];

Comment: But I dont find NSLog get printed and I m gettting an orange coloured line below the code..It is neither showing error nor warning at that orange line

Comment: dude its work fine mate just take my code now and paste in your viewWillAppear method and see what u get its working fine dude.. try it now and reply in any error u got ok dude..

Comment: use NSLog(@"isTheObjectThere %d",isTheObjectThere); instead of result use isTheObjectThere

Comment: @Sindhia you got it dude??

Answer (score 0):

```
BOOL isTheObjectThere = [array containsObject:weekday];
```

will not work, better try the following method.

```
    NSMutableArray* inputArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Sunday", @"Monday", @"Tuesday", nil];

for (NSString* item in inputArray)
{



if ([item rangeOfString:@"Sunday"].location != NSNotFound)


{
   //do something
  }



else


{
  //do something;
 } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *yourString = @"Monday";

for (NSString* item in inputArray){
if ([yourString rangeOfString:item].location != NSNotFound)
//Do something;

else
// Do the other Thing;
}
```